# Show that a transformation matrix is equal to the martix of eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The real symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ has unit eigenvectors $\mathbf x_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Thus we have, $A\mathbf x_i=\lambda_i \mathbf x_i$.

A $3\times 3$ matrix $C$ takes a vector in the orthogonal coordinate system with basis vectors $\hat{\mathbf e}_i$ and maps it into the orthogonal coordinate system with basis vectors $\mathbf x_i$, i.e., $\mathbf x_i=C\hat{\mathbf e}_i$. (Note that $C_{ij}= \hat{\mathbf e}_i\cdot \mathbf x_j$ and $C$ is an orthogonal matrix.) Show that the columns of $C$ are the unit eigenvectors of $A$.

It seems so obvious to me that the transformation matrix $C$ would be the eigenvector matrix. Is there a easy way to show this?

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "$C$ maps a vector $\mathbf{v}$ into the principal coordinate system of $A$"? Are you assuming your matrices are $3\times 3$?

Comment: @EuYu, I rephrased my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it holds that $C\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i = \mathbf{x}_i$ then the columns of $C$ are indeed the unit eigenvectors of $\mathbf{x}_i$. Note that right-multiplying $C$ by $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$ simply has the action of selecting its $i$th column; this fact simply follows from the definition of matrix multiplication.

More generally, if we have a vector $\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n\end{pmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$ then multiplying it to a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with columns $\mathbf{a}_i$ gives
$$A\mathbf{v} = v_1\mathbf{a}_1 + v_2\mathbf{a}_2 + \cdots + v_n\mathbf{a}_n$$

For $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$, all but the $i$th entry is zero and hence the result. The equation $C\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i = \mathbf{x}_i$ is in essence a short-hand for saying that the $i$th column of $C$ is $\mathbf{x}_i$.